# Discord.py Bot deleting bot message too

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm writing a simple script that exec if a simplified string is written in a channel, after that the user message gets deleted.
Or if the user send a message that is not one of the strings it to be deleted too.

However, even the bot message gets deleted too which are theses

```
       await message.channel.send(badr.mention)
       await message.channel.send(expired)
```

and

```
   await message.channel.send(author.mention)
   await message.channel.send(WL_message)
```

which is not what I'm aiming for I want only the member's message to get deleted not the bots.

```
 if (message.channel.id == 897508930744381491):
      author = message.author
      content = message.content
      expire = '||!WL xdxdxd||', '||!WL 432-234-4312-fas2||'
      Valied= '||!WL Furball2244||', '||!WL 432-234-4www312-32242||', 'Furball2244', '!WL Furball2244'

      if  message.content.startswith(expire):
       await message.delete()
       badr = author
       expired= "This code is expired, contact an admin in <#899289942897860659>, there is a chance they can add you manually"
       await message.channel.send(badr.mention)
       await message.channel.send(expired)

      if  message.content.startswith(Valied):
       ROLE = "Role55555"
       WL_message='Congratulations, now you have access to <#930074601436905522>, you enter your information there.'
       await message.channel.send(author.mention)
       await message.channel.send(WL_message)
       role = get(message.guild.roles, name=ROLE)
       await author.add_roles(role)
      
      else: await message.delete()
```

Is there a trick around it?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you want to delete the message the user sends, in which you would use

```
await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Hey gim! Babylon seems to be doing this within an `on_message` event rather than a command, so a different solution may be required. Do correct me if I'm wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for author to send message

```
def check(m):
    return message.author == oldmsg.author #To make sure it is the only message author is getting
msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=60.0, check=check)

if message.content == "your codes":
 # do stuff
 await message.delete()
```

This way you can delete the next message from the user right away. make sure you save the command author in a global dictionary or something!

Comment: I'm getting a self not defined error

Comment: Isn't there a way to exclude the Bots message from message.delete()?

Answer (score 0):

```
      elif message.author.id == 930374951935021096:
   return
  else: 
   await message.delete()
```

seems like just adding an elif solves the problem, regardless thank you for your reply.